# Python - Formatting specific data within text files

Tags: python

I have a number of log files I need extract and format data. some of these log files are very big with over 10,000 lines.

can anyone suggest a code sample to help me read a text file, remove unwanted lines, then edit the remaining lines into a particular format. i haven't been able to find any previous threads that have what I'm after.

An example of the data I need to edit is below:

```
136: add student 50000000 35011 / Y01T :Unknown id in field 3 - ignoring line

137: add student 50000000 5031 / Y01S :Unknown id in field 3 - ignoring line

138: add student 50000000 881 / Y01S :Unknown course idnumber in field 4 - ignoring line

139: add student 50000000 5732 / Y01S :Unknown id in field 3 - ignoring line

134: add student 50000000 W250 / Y02S :OK

135: add student 50000000 35033 / Y01T :OK
```

I need to search the file and delete any line that is suffixed with :OK.
Then, i need to edit the remaining lines in to a CSV format such as:

```
add,student,50000000,1234 / abcd
```

Any tips, code snippets, etc would be very helpful and i'll be most grateful. i'd try it first before asking, but I have little time to self teach python file access/string formatting. So please allow me to apologise in advance for not attempting it prior to asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'Add an input file as parameter'
    sys.exit(1)

print 'opening file: %s' % sys.argv[1]

with open(sys.argv[1]) as input, open('output', 'w+') as output:
    for line in input:
        if line is not None:
            if line == '\n':
                pass
            elif 'OK' in line:
                pass
            else:
                new_line = line.split(' ', 7)
                output.write('%s,%s,%s,%s / %s\n' % (new_line[1], new_line[2], new_line[3], new_line[4], new_line[6]))
                # just for checking purposes let's print the lines
                print '%s,%s,%s,%s / %s' % (new_line[1], new_line[2], new_line[3], new_line[4], new_line[6])
```

Watch out for the output file name!

Comment: I'll give it a go and play with the code.
Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the regular expression to suit your needs if they differ, and you can also modify the parameters of csv.writer if you need other delimiters:

```
import re, csv

regex = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+([\w/ ]+?):\s*(.+)")
with open("out.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    with open("log.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            m = regex.match(line)
            if m and m.group(6) != "OK":
                writer.writerow(m.groups()[1:-1])
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply. these are very helpful to me and I'm learning fast. very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. Being a newbie, the code I ended up with isn't as elegant, but it still does the job :).

```
#open the file and create the CSV after filtering the input file.
def openFile(filename, keyword): #defines the function to open the file. User to pass two variables.

    list = []
    string = ''

    f = open(filename, 'r') #opens the file as a read and places it into the variable 'f'.
    for line in f: #for each line in 'f'.
        if keyword in line: #check to see if the keyword is in the line.
            list.append(line) #add the line to the list.

    print(list) #test.

    for each in list: #filter and clean the info, format the info into a CSV format.
        choppy = each.partition(': ') #split to remove the prefix.
        chunk = choppy[2] #take the good string.
        choppy = chunk.partition(' :') #split to remove the suffix.
        chunk = choppy[0] #take the good string.
        strsplit = chunk.split(' ') #split the string by spaces ' '.
        line = strsplit[0] + ',' + strsplit[1] + ',' + strsplit[2] + ',' + strsplit[3] + ' ' + strsplit[4] + ' ' + strsplit[5] + '\n' #concatenate the strings.

        string = string + line #concatenate each line to create a single string.

    print(string) #test.

    f = open(keyword + '.csv', 'w') #open a file to write.
    f.write(string) #write the string to the file.
    f.close() #close the file.



openFile('russtest.txt', 'cat')
openFile('CRON ENROL LOG 200913.txt', 'field 4')
```

Thanks :).